# Releasing nested go module on GitHub. Getting it

Tags: go, github, import, repository, git-submodules

## How do I release submodule inside another module on GitHub and then get it as that release?

I have [github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr](https://github.com/Siiir/unsafe/tree/main/ptr) submodule nested inside [github.com/Siiir/unsafe](https://github.com/Siiir/unsafe) module-repository.

I've released v1.0.1 version of repository in 2022-09-28.
When I enter `go get github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr` (today 2022-09-29) in terminal, I get:

```
go: added github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr v0.0.0-20220928101416-cbfa3754033f
```

**v0.0.0-20220928101416-cbfa3754033f** version sugests no release of repo which has v1.0.1 release.
If I enter `go get github.com/Siiir/unsafe/`, everything works fine I get:

```
 go: added github.com/Siiir/unsafe v1.0.1
```

But the supermodule [github.com/Siiir/unsafe](https://github.com/Siiir/unsafe) is useless (here) by itself.
***UPDATE**: It was useless. After reading the answer I published v1.0.2, which doesn't have nested "go.mod" file and so now supermodule gives access to submodule.*
I want submodule [github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr](https://github.com/Siiir/unsafe/tree/main/ptr) in the same version as is the whole repo.

Comment: If the package github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr is versioned with the repo as a whole, then there's no need to create a separate module for the package.  Use the module at the root of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Cerise Limón comment resolves my problem:

> If the package github.com/Siiir/unsafe/ptr is versioned with the repo as a whole, then there's no need to create a separate module for the package. Use the module at the root of the repo.